# Generate igraphs with varied centralization

Tags: r, igraph

I am developing an estimation method for graphs. I need to test it's robustness on different `igraphs`. How do I generate (in R) several `igraphs` with varying graph level centralization? I am familiar with `sample_(...)`, that variations of 'sample_' allow me to generate graphs GIVEN a MODEL, but not given graph level centralization.

I would like to have for example:

```
graph_1 <- centralization=.50; graph_2 <- centralization=.30 . . . graph_n <- centralization=.00
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a baked in function in `igraph`, but you can generate graphs with a specific centralization using the degree sequence sampler: `sample_degseq`. The key is to find a degree distribution in which the sum of the differences between the maximum degree and each degree in the distribution is equal to the theoretical maximum * centralization.

This function does the trick, but a bit hacky:

```
sample_centr <- function(size, centralization, leeway = 50) {
  theoretical_max <- size * (size - 1)
  sum_diff <- theoretical_max * centralization

  # Must be an interger
  sum_diff <- round(sum_diff)

  sim_diff <- 0

  while (sim_diff < (sum_diff - leeway) | sim_diff > (sum_diff - leeway)) {

    # To deal with very low levels of centralization...
    if (centralization < 0.10) {
      max_deg <- floor(size * runif(1, 0, 1))
      degs <- floor(runif(size, min = max_deg - floor(max_deg*0.25), max_deg))
    } else {
      degs <- sample(1:size, size, replace=TRUE, prob=(1:size)^-2)
    }
    sim_diff <- sum(max(degs) - degs)
  }

  if (sum(degs) %% 2 != 0) { 
    degs[1] <- degs[1] + 1 
    }

  g <- sample_degseq(degs)
  return(g)
}
```

Of course this is only for degree centralization. Betweenness centralization would be much, much more challenging, I think.

```
> g <- sample_centr(100, 0.5, 0)
> centr_degree(g)
$res
  [1]  1  1  2  1 53  2  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  3  1  1  5  2  1  1  1  1  5  1  7  1 18  1  1
 [33]  1  1  1  2  1  8  2  5  6  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  7  1  1  2  1  2  1  9 51  4 12  1
 [65]  1  1  1  1  2  6  3  2  1  2  2  1  4  1  1 25  1  5  1  1  1  2  3 10  1  2  1  3  1  1  2  2
 [97]  2  3  1  1

$centralization
[1] 0.5

$theoretical_max
[1] 9900
```